Why is Dependent Arising (Paṭiccasamuppāda) not included in Satipatthana Sutta?
I ask a similar question here, but why is it that dependent origination is not part of the Satipathanasutta?  There are a few references to the origin of the body in section 1 (considering the body) but not section 4 (teachings & techniques)...would it be useful if it were?

The Four Noble Truths are listed in the Satipatthana Sutta.


The Four Noble Truths

And further, monks, a monk lives contemplating mental objects in the mental objects of the four noble
truths.
How, monks, does a monk live contemplating mental objects in the
mental objects of the four noble truths?
Herein, monks, a monk knows, "This is suffering," according to
reality; he knows, "This is the origin of suffering," according to
reality; he knows, "This is the cessation of suffering," according to
reality; he knows "This is the road leading to the cessation of
suffering," according to reality.
Thus he lives contemplating mental objects in mental objects
internally, or he lives contemplating mental objects in mental objects
externally, or he lives contemplating mental objects in mental objects
internally and externally. He lives contemplating origination-factors
in mental objects, or he lives contemplating dissolution-factors in
mental objects, or he lives contemplating
origination-and-dissolution-factors in mental objects.[27] Or his
mindfulness is established with the thought, "Mental objects exist,"
to the extent necessary just for knowledge and mindfulness, and he
lives detached, and clings to nothing in the world. Thus, monks, a
monk lives contemplating mental objects in the mental objects of the
four noble truths.
Satipatthana Sutta

Dependent Arising = Second Noble Truth

And what is the noble truth of the origination of stress?
From ignorance as a requisite condition come fabrications. From
fabrications as a requisite condition comes consciousness. From
consciousness as a requisite condition comes name-&-form. From
name-&-form as a requisite condition come the six sense media. From
the six sense media as a requisite condition comes contact. From
contact as a requisite condition comes feeling. From feeling as a
requisite condition comes craving. From craving as a requisite
condition comes clinging. From clinging as a
requisite condition comes becoming. From becoming as a requisite
condition comes birth. From birth as a requisite condition, then old
age & death, sorrow, lamentation, pain, distress, & despair come into
play. Such is the origination of this entire mass of stress &
suffering.
This is called the noble truth of the origination of stress.
AN 3.61

